# What has to be done to have a Java program search Google?

Tags: java, connection, google-search

Here is the idea:

1. a program (in Java) will take an input
2. the program takes the input and uses it somewhere online to get results
3. it takes the results it got online and shows it on the program interface

It is sort of like how you can search through a Google Desktop Application instead of going on a browser?

I just need a general push towards the right direction on this. (maybe a certain method I should look for) I'm not very familiar with the Java API.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what API you're trying to communicate with? There's no general answer to this question.

Comment: I'd figure I need to have some action listener along with the input and define some action, which will have the program take the input and use it to retrieve data from a website.

Comment: From what web site? Specifics, please.

Comment: I am looking at the text analysis tool on http://www.usingenglish.com/members/text-analysis/

Comment: AFAIU Google removed access to their search API, and do not encourage scraping Google pages for hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java's standard HttpURLConnection to search the content. Then to parse the response all you need is [Apache tika](http://tika.apache.org/index.html) which is used to extract text from HTML pages.

Here is a simple example of using Url Connection :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class SimpleHTTPRequest {

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      HttpURLConnection connection = null;
      DataOutputStream wr = null;
      BufferedReader rd  = null;
      StringBuilder sb = null;
      String line = null;

      URL serverAddress = null;

      try {
          serverAddress = new URL("http://www.google.com/search?q=test");
          //set up out communications stuff
          connection = null;

          //Set up the initial connection
          connection = (HttpURLConnection)serverAddress.openConnection();
          connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
          connection.setDoOutput(true);
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.setUseCaches(false);
          connection.setRequestProperty ( "Content-type","text/xml" ); 
          connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
          String strData = URLEncoder.encode("test","UTF-8");
          connection.setRequestProperty ( "Content-length", "" + strData.length ());  
          connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
          connection.connect();

          //get the output stream writer and write the output to the server
          //not needed in this example
          wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
          wr.writeBytes("q="+strData);
          wr.flush();

          //read the result from the server
          rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
          sb = new StringBuilder();

          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
          {
              sb.append(line + '\n');
          }

          System.out.println(sb.toString());

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
          //close the connection, set all objects to null
          connection.disconnect();
          rd = null;
          sb = null;
          wr = null;
          connection = null;
      }
  }
}
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429814/how-can-i-use-html-parser-with-apache-tika-in-java-to-extract-all-html-tags) you find an example of extracting text using apache tika

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn about Java socket programming and how a web server works. Along with this, you use `HttpURLConnection` class to establish the connection to the web server and you can download the content.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use open source lib [Apache Http components](http://hc.apache.org/). This eases the job.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use URL Class to connect with web.

For example

```
        url1 = new URL(url);
        InputStream input=url1.openStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(input);
        dis=new DataInputStream(bis);
       // byte[] buffer=new byte[1000];
        String data="";
        while(dis.available()!=0)
        {
            data+=dis.readLine();
        }

        jobj=new JSONObject(data);
```