# How to find text in html using regex

Tags: java, html, regex

I'd like to find all text in correct html file.
Example:

```
<div style="color: red;">text<span>another text</span>another text<img src="some_image"/></div>
```

How can i do that in java?

Comment: by text u meant plain text?

Comment: Regular Expressions are generally considered a bad idea for parsing HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Something like JSoup will get you the plain text content first

Comment: Rinku yes I mean plain text. I'm wrote something like this: >([^<>]+)< but is not good enough. When I add lookahead it stop working (?=>)([^<>]+)(?=<).

Comment: I think you'll find some good answers for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, Regex is a bad idea. I think to parse HTML probably the most well known library is [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) and a very nice tutorial by MK Yong is [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Apache Tika http://tika.apache.org/0.7/gettingstarted.html

Example Using Tika for .html: [How can I use the HTML parser with Apache Tika in Java to extract all HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429814/how-can-i-use-the-html-parser-with-apache-tika-in-java-to-extract-all-html-tags)